# Computer seems to be frozen during reboot after installation. How long should the reboot take?

Tags: kernel, startup

I'm attempting to dual-boot my laptop with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.10. Everything to my knowledge has gone perfectly, up until now. The installation was success. Consequently, the computer began the typical reboot. A black screen appeared with a bunch of esoteric code. It looks like an enumerated list of tasks the PC is trying to complete. Unfortunately, once it got to step 53, it stopped there and hasn't done anything else for the last hour and a half. The computer is obviously still processing something due to how heated it's getting. I'm just concerned that something has gone terribly wrong. Can anyone please help? The text reads:

```
[    53.252069]  CR2:  fffffffffffffffffffffff
```

"Computer seems to be frozen during reboot after installation. How long should the reboot take?"

Comment: `53.252069` is not the number of a step, but the number of seconds since the system was started. That line looks to me as a piece of a kernel panic. It would be helpful if you could post the whole screen (a photo is fine). If we find out that this is a kernel panic, then you will need to [report a bug](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bugs/ReportingBugs).

Answer (score 1):

If your computer takes more than a couple of minutes, then something is definitely wrong.

First, try to restart again. Does that work?

If so, then it may have just been a fluke. It happens sometimes, for various reasons, and often a restart will make everything go smoothly (often, the computer will detect that something didn't go right and will try to fix the cause).

If not, does it stop at the same place? "Step 53" doesn't tell us anything, and probably isn't a step at all. Take a look at the text of the "step," as well as that of the "steps" before it. If it stops at the same place, what is it stopping at/what is the "step" before it? That might give an indication as to what's failing.

Do you have any printers or other USB or external devices hooked up? If so, unplug them and see if it can boot successfully. If it can, reintroduce the devices one at a time until you get it to break again. I've seen instances where a computer won't boot, or takes a long time to boot, due to a USB device (in my case, a printer) causing trouble. This may be due to a faulty cable, faulty port, or you've simply overloaded the power draw of that USB block. Replace cables or move where you have things plugged in as needed to get it to boot again with all devices.

If that doesn't work, try reinstalling the OS (if you want to be doubly sure, redownload the ISO, check the MD5 sum, and remake your boot disk). Sometimes, the copy process doesn't copy quite right, for a number of different reasons, and a reinstall fixes things.